# What happens to passengers who are identified as having a fever when entering the US?

Tags: usa, health, event-based-effects, covid-19

Let's say one is flying into SFO tomorrow from China and encounters one of the thermal scanners as they leave the aircraft. This passenger has a fever, which may or may not be caused by the Wuhan coronavirus. How would the airport authorities deal with such a passenger?

Some bonus questions:

- Does it matter if you're a US citizen? E.g. would they just deport a French national to avoid the risk?
- Does it matter if you have health insurance? Would the government authorities pay for any mandatory procedures or is that up to the passenger?
- Does it matter if the fever started before or during the flight? Would the passenger be prosecuted if they board the plane while knowing they're having flu-like symptoms?

Creating this question as the US authorities are currently expanding their screening of international passengers, so it's very much relevant.

Comment: Given the current travel restrictions, it is unlikely that a French citizen would be able to board the plane in the first place (unless they were in the immediate family of a US citizen or permanent resident), so the first question wouldn't arise.  [See this question.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153131/what-are-the-current-travel-restrictions-on-individuals-entering-the-united-stat)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Though I myself have PR status in Europe, US, and Canada -- all while staying in another country to avoid the coronavirus.  Without taking my relatives' nationalities into account.  So it's not as unlikely as you think.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.